# What does "= +" do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Was reading through Douglas Crockford's code [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/browser.js) and saw a line

```
var value = +node.getValue();
```

but I don't see anything at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp which corresponds to an `= +` or a way that `+` can be used as a unary operator. So what does this mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-` and `+` operators are both unary in JS and, before forcing the value's sign, must convert the value to a number.

Obviously `-` will convert to a number and invert the sign, but `+` only does the first part. Running `+"100"` will return the number `100`.

This behavior is explicitly stated [in the spec at 11.4.6](https://es5.github.io/#x11.4.6), where the unary `+` operator is defined:

> The unary + operator converts its operand to Number type.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a quick way to make sure the variable is an INT, (vs. a STR or BOOL, e.g.).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to what's been said do the following:

```
var a = +'4';
var b = '4';

console.log(typeof(a));//Number
console.log(typeof(b));//String
```